# Theme shown without styles

Tags: 8, theming, configuration

I executed the config:import: import successfully, but now it seems that the theme settings are no longer found.
The site is now seen as in the attached image

[image: drupal theme problem]

How can I solve the problem?

Note: I don't use bootstrap theme. I imported the configuration I had previously exported from another machine on Ubuntu. This problem is on a Windows machine.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap theme ?

Comment: I don't use bootstrap theme. I imported the configuration I had previously exported from another machine on Ubuntu. This problem is on a Windows machine

Comment: It's look like your theme not loading css and js files. can you please check error in console

Comment: Please read over your theme's generates HTML, "view source" in your browser. And let's us know if the CSS:JS is full out missing or if you are getting a 404 type error for those files.

Comment: In Configuration -> Performance I have removed the Aggregate CCS files and JS files checkbox and now it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check and confirm that the theme files are exactly were they should be.
2. Make sure the /files directory exists and writable (NOT 777 permissions though)
3. Double check and confirm that Drupal can access the files directory via configurations
4. Clear the Drupal cache

If the theme is using external CSS or JavaScript files, make sure they are accessible. (most cases its an internet connection especially for front-end  frameworks like Bootstrap)

Comment: In the chrome debugger I see this: 
Refused to apply style from  [.....]  because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: In Configuration -> Performance I have removed the Aggregate CCS files and JS files checkbox and now it seems to work